# HTML Div not Showing

Tags: html, svg, uiimageview

I have a query: My HTML code shows some SVG gauge(taken from google-chartdiv), I want to display it twice on my page but it appears on first time and after that no matter how many  I place in HTML code it does not show. How to display it for multiple times in one HTML page. Please advise.

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
  <div class="col-md-12 gage">
  <h1>Avg Handle Time (Sec)</h1>
  <div id="chartdiv" style="width:350px; height:300px;"></div>
  <span>@ViewBag.Name</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
  <div class="col-md-12 gage">
  <h1>Service Level %</h1>
  <div id="chartdiv" style="width:350px; height:300px;"></div>
  <span>@ViewBag.Age</span>
   </div>
```

My chartdiv code is:

```
<script>
        var chart;
        var arrow;
        var axis;

        AmCharts.ready(function () {
            // create angular gauge
            chart = new AmCharts.AmAngularGauge();
            chart.addTitle("Speedometer");
            // In gauge.js   has Nailradius , set the circular bottom of needle from there

            // create axis
            axis = new AmCharts.GaugeAxis();
            axis.startValue = 0;
            axis.axisThickness = 5;
            axis.valueInterval = 50;
            axis.endValue = 300;

            // color bands
            var band1 = new AmCharts.GaugeBand();
            band1.startValue = 0;
            band1.endValue = 180;
            band1.innerRadius = "94%"; // The thickness of Color Scheme lesser % = thick color
            band1.color = "#00CC00";

            var band2 = new AmCharts.GaugeBand();
            band2.startValue = 180;
            band2.endValue = 240;
            band2.color = "#ffac29";
            band2.innerRadius = "94%"; // The thickness of Color Scheme lesser % = thick color

            var band3 = new AmCharts.GaugeBand();
            band3.startValue = 240;
            band3.endValue = 300;
            band3.color = "#ea3838";
            band3.innerRadius = "94%";  // The thickness of Color Scheme lesser % = thick color

            axis.bands = [band1, band2, band3];

            // bottom text
            axis.bottomTextYOffset = -20;
            axis.setBottomText("0 km/h");
            chart.addAxis(axis);

            // gauge arrow
            arrow = new AmCharts.GaugeArrow();
            arrow.color = "#0000";  // Arrow color set to Black
            arrow.startWidth = "10";  //This is the width of Arrow connection with Base Circle
            arrow.radius = "100";  // This is the area covered by needle during motion

            chart.addArrow(arrow);

            chart.write("chartdiv1");

            // change value every 2 seconds
            setInterval(randomValue, 2000);
        });

        // set random value
        function randomValue() {
            var value = Math.round(Math.random() * 200);
            arrow.setValue(value);
            axis.setBottomText(value + " km/h");

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: You can't have more than one element with the same id. You'll have to show the code that generates the chart.

Comment: use seperate id to draw the multiple chart on your page id is used to unique not for duplicate. otherwise use class attribute as same

Comment: Please advise how can I change the ID of chartdiv, I atlast get the problem that ID is not unique.

Comment: I used same class name in both <div> but still the same Issue.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your currently working svg image

Comment: I am using d3.js Here i write a function to create a chart and i called multiple times for multiple image with different selectors (ids). like chart1, chart2,.....

Comment: Thanks Joyson- Its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was with the CSS scripts referred in HTML file. I was giving wrong Paths of CSS file having my SVG gauge. One path was correct while other was not pointing Correct.